# Debugging small javascript with exponents

Tags: javascript

```
n = 1;
    while (n < 1024) {
        alert(Math.pow(n, 2));
        n = n + 2;
    }
```

How can I make this display the powers of 2 from 2^0 to 2^10 inclusive i.e. (1-1024) and end once it reaches 1024 in Javascript

Comment: Please update the question title to match your actual question.

Comment: For starters you probably want `n` to go from 0 to 10 and not 1 to 1024.

Comment: Either you spend very little time and effort, or you have immense issues translating thoughts into code. You want 2^0 to 2^10, so the exponent varies from 0-10. The only variable you have is `n`, so to make it easier, rename that to `exponent`, to reflect what it will be. Then it should (imho, but apparently not) immediately be clear, that starting at `n = 1` is not what you want, that neither is `n < 1024`, that `Math.pow` has "exponent" as the second argument, not the first, and i can't even understand, where the `+ 2` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
for(let n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
            console.log(2 ** n)
        }
```

This logs the answer of each loop iteration. As Pointy suggested in the comment, we have to make the n value iterate from 1 to 10, since that is the variable that generates the output, whereas the 1024 is simply the output that comes from the power values. You could also use Math.pow as follows:

```
for(let n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                console.log(Math.pow(2, n))
            }
```

Implementing Secan's suggestion, here is a function which will take any number as a parameter:

```
function foo(x, exp) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= exp; i++) {
        console.log(x ** i)
    }
}
```

So to apply this to the original answer, we would call it like this:

```
foo(2, 10)
```

Comment: If you want to create a function to handle this issue, I think it would probably be worth making it reusable by passing the base and the exponent as arguments, so that you can call it as `foo(2, 10)` or `foo(3, 3)`. ;)

Comment: Imho it would be worth it to start at `n = 0`, actually fulfilling the task.

Comment: Good points. I've implemented these suggestions.

Comment: Ehmmm... nope; that is not how you would implement my suggestion.

Comment: True, don't know why I didn't notice that. Now, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the ambuiguity with my original question. I've figured it out-

```
n=0;
    while (n <= 10) {
        alert(Math.pow(2, n));
        n = n + 1;
    }
```

Setting n=0, n<=10 in while and changing n + 1 instead of 2 resolved my issue. Thanks for your responses!